# auto mount HFS+ filesystem from disk image (.dmg file)

Tags: filesystem, mount, dmg, hfs+, automount

I'd like to auto mount my dmg file which represent disk image with single HFS+ partition upon every boot. is it possible through autofs ? do I have to set the location of the dmg file in any configuration file (`/etc/...`)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add the **.dmg** *file* to your **Login Items** in: **System Preferences** > **Users & Groups** > (**you**) > **Login Items**

The **.dmg** *file* will then automatically be mounted when you login.

---

**Update to address comment:** "Is there any API to add item to login items programmatically?"

One programatic way I know of, it can be done with **AppleScript**:

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
tell application "System Events" to ¬
    make new login item with properties ¬
        {name:"Mount DMG", path:"/path/to/filename.dmg", hidden:true}
```

- Change "Mount DMG" and "/path/to/filename.dmg" as appropriate.

It can also be done from **Terminal** using, using the `osascript` *command*, with the same **AppleScript** *command*:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to make new login item with properties {name:"Mount DMG", path:"/path/to/filename.dmg", hidden:true}'
```

- Change "Mount DMG" and "/path/to/filename.dmg" as appropriate.

Comment: Hi and thanks for you reply, is there any API to add item to login items pro grammatically ?

Comment: @Zohar81, I've updated my answer to address your comment.